# Azure Search Data Retrieval

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

UseCase:

Assume that i pushed resident data into Azure Search, with City field as searchable and resident name  field as retrievable.

If i just search on City, can Azure search return all records.

Lets assume i have close to 10M records per city.

Bottom line is am trying to understand the retrieval limitation for Azure Search.

Note: I know i can use Databricks/Spark or equivalent solutions to query directly from DB, but this question is purely on Azure search standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get more than 1000 records per request.

You could read from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#api-response-limits)

> Maximum 1000 documents returned per page of search results Maximum 100
>   suggestions returned per Suggest API request

Comment: Do note that the maximum of 1000 documents is "per page" of results, and it is only 50 documents per page by default.  There is documentation on how to work with paging with Azure Search to eventually retrieve all of your results here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Search-Documents